# jQgrid guriddo - how to create duration column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need create column of duration. 
I have duration in seconds but I need show time by format like 'H:i:s'.

When I use date formatter and have time 60 seconds grid show me value '01:01' but I need only '00:01'.

Is it possible to create duration column in colModel without modify or optimize data?

Maybe use date formatter but auto decrement value -3600.

My column settings are

```
formatter: date
formatoptions: 
   srcformat: "U"
   "newformat": "H:i:s"
```

I use the newest version of jqgrid guriddo.

**UPDATE:** 
EXAMPLE DATA:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "records": 3,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "FIRST ROW",
      "duration": 1139
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "SECOND ROW",
      "duration": 60
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "THIRD ROW",
      "duration": 15336
    }
  ],
  "total": 1
}
```

Comment: Can you please post example data that coming form the server or local array?

Comment: I have tested this and it is working fine for me - it shows 00:01:00. Please let us know which version exactley of Guriddo jqGrid is used and if possible prepare a example in jsfiddle so that we can look into the problem. When prepare example, please use non minified version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where is the problem. jqGrid gets the local timezone and convert it according to this.

I suggest you to use a custom formatter in this case instead of the build in one. So replace the formatter : date with

```
formatter : function(val, opt, data ) {
    var offset = (new Date( val )).getTimezoneOffset();
    return  $.jgrid.parseDate.call(this, 'U', (parseFloat(val) + offset*60), 'H:i:s');
}
```

This way any user from any time zone will see 00:01:00